# Issues with odometry in robot_localization

Tags: navigation, ekf, ros-kinetic, robot-localization, ekf-localization-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using the robot_localization package with ROS Kinetic and I'm trying to fuse the IMU and GPS data from the Matrice M100 similar to the work done [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/304491/robot_localization-problems/?comment=308977#post-id-308977).

My issue is the odometry/gps topic looks wacky and isn't in line with what I expect the output to be. If you take a look at the picture below, red is the real drone odometry, purple is the `odometry/filtered_map topic`  and green is `odometry/gps`. I can't upload files yet but you can see it at this [link](https://imgur.com/a/KZ2ynUM). Occasionally, I experience jumps but nothing too big at all. I recorded a bag file and plotted the coordinates of the drone and raw GPS and `gps/filtered` seem to be close enough as seen [here](https://imgur.com/a/i42S6Rf): however, the 3d position messages on the odometry topic is inaccurate as shown [here](https://imgur.com/a/ejE87tJ):  I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong in the configuration .

I've also attached a copy of the bag file [here:](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1A39e1qIwhbo_NCkZJwYrf82jD4nZh0SM)  Any help is appreciated.

Here's a sample of my dual_ekf_navsat file:

```
ekf_se_odom:
  frequency: 30
  sensor_timeout: 0.1
  two_d_mode: false
  transform_time_offset: 0.0
  transform_timeout: 0.0
  print_diagnostics: true
  debug: false

  map_frame: map
  odom_frame: odom
  base_link_frame: m100/base_link
  world_frame: odom

  odom0: dji_odom
  odom0_config: [true, true, true,
                 true, true, true,
                 true,  true,  true,
                 true, true, true,
                 true, true, true]
  odom0_queue_size: 10
  odom0_nodelay: true
  odom0_differential: false
  odom0_relative: false

  imu0: imu/data
  imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                true,  true,  true,
                false, false, false,
                true,  true,  true,
                true,  true,  true]
  imu0_nodelay: false
  imu0_differential: false
  imu0_relative: false
  imu0_queue_size: 10
  imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

  use_control: false

  process_noise_covariance: [0.05, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0.05, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0.06, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0.03, 0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0.03, 0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.06, 0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.025, 0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0.025, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0.04, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0.01, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0.01, 0,    0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0.02, 0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.015]

  initial_estimate_covariance: [0.503, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,   0.503, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,   0.503, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0.05,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0.05,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.05, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,   0.115,  0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.115,  0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.115,  0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9,   0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     1e-9,   0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     1e-9,   0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     1e-9,  0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    1e-9,  0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    1e-9]

ekf_se_map:
  frequency: 30
  sensor_timeout: 0.1
  two_d_mode: false
  transform_time_offset: 0.0
  transform_timeout: 0.0
  print_diagnostics: true
  debug: false

  map_frame: map
  odom_frame: odom
  base_link_frame: m100/base_link
  world_frame: map

  odom0: dji_odom
  odom0_config: [true, true, true,
                 true, true, true,
                 true,  true,  true,
                 true, true, true,
                 true, true, true]
  odom0_queue_size: 10
  odom0_nodelay: true
  odom0_differential: false
  odom0_relative: false

  odom1: odometry/gps
  odom1_config: [true,  true,  true,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false]
  odom1_queue_size: 10
  odom1_nodelay: true
  odom1_differential: false
  odom1_relative: false

  imu0: imu/data
  imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                true,  true,  true,
                false, false, false,
                true,  true, true,
                true,  true,  true]
  imu0_nodelay: true
  imu0_differential: false
  imu0_relative: false
  imu0_queue_size: 10
  imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

  use_control: false

  process_noise_covariance: [0.00125, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0.00125, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0.00125, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0.03,  0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0.03,  0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.03, 0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.025,   0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0.025,   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0.025,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0.01,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0.01,  0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0.01,  0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01,  0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01,  0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01]

  initial_estimate_covariance: [0.03, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,   0.03, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,   0.0003, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0.05,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0.05,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.05, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,   0.115,  0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.115,  0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.115,  0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-3,   0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     1e-3,   0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     1e-3,   0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     1e-3,  0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    1e-3,  0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    1e-3]

navsat_transform:
  frequency: 30
  delay: 3.0
  magnetic_declination_radians: 0.013945181  # For Latitude: 52° 46' 0" N Longitude: 1° 11' 60" W
  yaw_offset: 0  # IMU reads 0 facing magnetic north, not east
  zero_altitude: true
  broadcast_utm_transform: true
  publish_filtered_gps: true
  use_odometry_yaw: false
  wait_for_datum: false
```

---

Edit: @TomMoore. Hi,

> You have zero_altitude set to true,
> so that makes sense.

I think this effectively answered the question, Nevertheless I just ran some tests again and this is a sample of what my messages look like: `dji_odom` and `dji_gps` are pretty much taken off the measurements on the drone and the position_covariance field isn't populated.

**dji_gps:**

```
header: 
  seq: 571
  stamp: 
    secs: 1547133552
    nsecs: 459178464
  frame_id: "gps_link"
status: 
  status: 0
  service: 0
latitude: 52.7559213512
longitude: -1.24558837273
altitude: 0.0
position_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
position_covariance_type: 0
```

**dji_odom:**

```
header: 
  seq: 24997
  stamp: 
    secs: 1547133623
    nsecs: 583466919
  frame_id: "map"
child_frame_id: "m100/base_link"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 0.19640581586
      y: 0.08017268792
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 8.78677365389e-07
      y: 1.98371220381e-07
      z: 0.98597292863
      w: -0.166905314502
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: -0.0
    angular: 
      x: -0.00928046740592
      y: -0.00753092952073
      z: -0.0100603736937
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

**imu_data**

```
 seq: 69442
  stamp: 
    secs: 1547133697
    nsecs: 982469760
  frame_id: "body_FLU"
orientation: 
  x: 8.78677365389e-07
  y: 1.98371220381e-07
  z: 0.98597292863
  w: -0.166905314502
orientation_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
angular_velocity: 
  x: -0.0090597756207
  y: -0.0082494430244
  z: -0.00930665619671
angular_velocity_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
linear_acceleration: 
  x: -0.727012836367
  y: -0.274564963371
  z: 9.64790552562
linear_acceleration_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

**odometry_gps**

```
header: 
  seq: 344
  stamp: 
    secs: 1547133949
    nsecs: 810438520
  frame_id: "map"
child_frame_id: ''
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 33.9151475955
      y: -15.0338618625
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      w: 1.0
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

And here is an output of what the plot looks like when I set X Y Z on `dji_odom`  for both `ekf_se_map` and `ekf_se_odom` to true. The red line is the raw GPS data while the blue line is GPS estimates from `/gps/filtered`. I'm turning off the GPS sensor input to the EKF every ten seconds.
The output looks like [this](https://imgur.com/a/TCADr0y) but when i set it to false on both `ekf_se_map` and `ekf_se_odom`, I get [this](https://imgur.com/a/scOiSs5).

Additionally, only setting `dji_odom` to false on `ekf_se_odom` returns [this](https://imgur.com/wCns6lK) which is the expected output I'm looking for.

What are your thoughts on this?

**EDIT:** IMU at rest facing east reads: So If I'm correct I need to enter the `orientation.w` 0.922 as my offset?

```
orientation: 
  x: -0.0363018553366
  y: 0.0232600556101
  z: 0.38423554048
  w: 0.922227843076
orientation_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
angular_velocity: 
  x: -0.01088836696
  y: -0.00634883204475
  z: -0.00847856514156
angular_velocity_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
linear_acceleration: 
  x: -0.763442474619
  y: -0.183017604768
  z: 9.59214563978
linear_acceleration_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/309717/issues-with-odometry-in-robot_localization/) by [marinePhD](https://answers.ros.org/users/36566/marinephd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2018-11-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please post sample messages from every sensor input.

Can you explain what is wacky in the images you posted? It looks to me that the state estimate is closely tracking your odometry, and that the GPS odom values are just bound to the ground plane. You have `zero_altitude` set to *true*, so that makes sense. And remember that there are no headings associated with the GPS poses, so they won't look the same.

Anyway, another issue with your configuration is that you are fusing absolute X, Y, and Z position from your odometry, as well as absolute X, Y, and Z position from your GPS data. If your odometry is subject to drift (and I assume it is), then you will reach a point where those positions don't match. When that happens, the filter will start leaping back and forth between the two measurement sources. An alternative symptom - and I think you're seeing it - is that if your odometry covariance is much smaller than your GPS position covariance, the filter is going to effectively follow the odometry values. But again, I can't really say that with any certainty until you post sample messages.

Also, it looks like you left the `navsat_transform_node` `yaw_offset` comment in there from the sample config file, but changed the `yaw_offset` value to 0. Does your IMU read 0 facing east?

Finally, if your odometry source is internally integrating velocity data to get position, and then you fuse *both* the position and velocities in the EKF, you're biasing the EKF. If I were you, I'd set the first three values (X, Y, and Z) to false in your EKF configuration for *dji_odom*.

**EDIT in response to updates**:

OK, a few things:

- Your `dji_gps` data is given in the `gps_link` frame. I assume a transform exists from *m100/base_link* to *gps*?
- You `imu_data` topic is in the *body_FLU* frame. I assume you have a transform from *m100/base_link* to *body_FLU*?
- Your `dji_odom` pose data is given in the *map* frame, yet you are trying to fuse it absolutely (i.e., the pose data, and not the velocity data) into your *odom* frame EKF. That's going to require the *map*->*odom* transform, which the *map* frame EKF is itself producing. Since you have an IMU providing your orientation, I would recommend that you fuse *only* velocity data from `dji_odom` in both your EKF instances. That, or (a) change the `frame_id` to *odom* in your `dji_odom` topic, (b) fuse only the pose data from `dji_odom`, and (c) fuse only velocity/acceleration data from the IMU (a, b, and c are for the *odom* frame EKF; for the map frame, I'd flip them and use velocity from the odometry and orientation from the IMU).
- The `w` component of a quaternion isn't the same as the yaw component of orientation, so you'll need to convert that quaternion to Euler angles to get the offset. My guess is that you just want `pi/2`, and then your magnetic declination correction value will take care of the rest.

Overall, my general advice with these applications is to start small. Start with a single EKF instance, and just the odom data. Convince yourself that the data is being fused properly, then add in the IMU. Check if the output changes as you'd expect from the odometry-only run. Make sure the run is long enough to encompass a lot of turns, such that your odometry yaw will differ from the IMU yaw, thereby ensuring that you aren't fusing absolute yaw from two sources.

When you're convinced everything is working, move to the *map* frame EKF. Repeat the process again: start with just odom, then IMU, then add the GPS last. When you add the GPS data, at first, *don't* fuse it with the EKF. Just run `navsat_transform_node` and plot the output alongside your *map* frame EKF output. They ought to align for a while, until drift carries the EKF instance away. Then you can fuse the GPS data.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2019-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marinePhD](https://answers.ros.org/users/36566/marinephd/) on 2019-01-10**:
@Tom Moore, Edited the original question.